# Javascript issue "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, automationstudio

I have a JSON file from which I need to extract some information about ordered items. i believe my JSON is configured properly with an array called 'items'.

Whenever I try to run my code, it gives me the error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

If I remove the following lines then my query gets validated:

```
var orderedItems = items.map(item => `${item.qty_ordered} ${item.extension_attributes.material_number}`);
var orderedItemsString = orderedItems.join(' / ');
```

This is (part of) the code I am running. Can anyone help me understanding what I'm doing wrong here? Been trying different things for hours now.

```
try {
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var action = "ClearData";
    var props = { CustomerKey: 'DATAEXTENSIONTARGET' };
    var clearData = prox.performItem("DataExtension", props, action);
    var data = retrieveAllRecords("DATAEXTENSIONSOURCE");
    var columns = ["SFID", "Email", "Locale", "FirstName", "LastName", "PostalCode", "City", "AccountSegment", "CountryCode", "Language", "CreatedDate", "Magento_ID", "IsPersonAccount", "hasSampleItems", "hasCatalogItems", "hasRegularItems", "AmountSampleOrder", "AmountCatalogueOrder", "AmountProductOrder", "NetAmount", "Items"];

    var values = [];
    if (data && data.length > 0) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var SFID = data[i].SFID;
            var Email = data[i].Email;
            var Locale = data[i].Locale;
            var FirstName = data[i].FirstName;
            var LastName = data[i].LastName;
            var payload = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(data[i].Payload);
            var PostalCode = data[i].PostalCode;
            var City = data[i].City;
            var AccountSegment = data[i].AccountSegment;
            var CountryCode = data[i].CountryCode;
            var Language = data[i].Language;
            var CreatedDate = data[i].CreatedDate;
            var Magento_ID = data[i].Magento_ID;
            var IsPersonAccount = data[i].IsPersonAccount;
            var hasSampleItems = data[i].hasSampleItems;
            var hasCatalogItems = data[i].hasCatalogItems;
            var hasRegularItems = data[i].hasRegularItems;
            var AmountSampleOrder = data[i].AmountSampleOrder;
            var AmountCatalogueOrder = data[i].AmountCatalogueOrder;
            var AmountProductOrder = data[i].AmountProductOrder;

            var NetAmount = payload.grand_total;
            var items = payload.items;
            var orderedItems = items.map(item => `${item.qty_ordered} ${item.extension_attributes.material_number}`);
            var orderedItemsString = orderedItems.join(' / ');


            values = [SFID, Email, Locale, FirstName, LastName, PostalCode, City, AccountSegment, CountryCode, Language, CreatedDate, Magento_ID, IsPersonAccount, hasSampleItems, hasCatalogItems, hasRegularItems, AmountSampleOrder, AmountCatalogueOrder, AmountProductOrder, NetAmount, orderedItemsString];

            var rows = Platform.Function.InsertData("DATAEXTENSIONTARGET", columns, values);

        }
    }
} catch (e) {
    Write("<br>" + Stringify(e));
}
```

Comment: Do you know which line is throwing your error?

Comment: If I remove this one, then the script gets validated:
var orderedItems = items.map(item => `${item.qty_ordered} ${item.extension_attributes.material_number}`);
            var orderedItemsString = orderedItems.join(' / ');

Comment: Another piece of imformation, no idea if it's helpful: if I only extract payload.items into a data extension column, I get this value: System.Collections.ArrayList

Comment: If you remove those lines then `orderedItemsString` won't exist when you use it in to populated `values`?

Comment: Indeed, doesn't exist, isn't used to populate DE

Comment: Can you do a `console.log` and check the value of `payload.items`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that, relatively new here. I do know when I export it to a DE, I get this: System.Collections.ArrayList

Comment: yeah array.map is not a native capability in SFMC SSJS, you would have to polyfill. Here is a quick reference on native array methods and which are native in SSJS as well and which need fills that I wrote: https://gortonington.com/javascript-array-methods-in-sfmc/

Answer (score 0):

Found out myself how to solve it after all:

```
...
            var items = payload.items;
            var itemsStringArray = []
            for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
            var item = items[j];
            var itemString = item.qty_ordered + " " + item.sku;
            itemsStringArray.push(itemString);
        }

        // Join the array of item strings into a single string using ' / ' as separator
        var itemsString = itemsStringArray.join(' / ');
```